# How to set source image for a button in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, gameobject

I have a `button` UI game object. That doesn't have an image from the start. I fetch a image from the `server` and then set it as `button` image. Here is the code:

```
WWW w = new WWW (newUrl);
yield return w;
Adbutton.GetComponent<Image>().sprite =  Sprite.Create(w.texture,new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100),new Vector2(0,0));
```

The button does change color but image is not set. Help me out!

Comment: wB.texture? You might want to include the full scenario

Comment: Sorry that was w.texture. I have edited my code.

Comment: What type of file does newUrl point to?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a "RawImage" rather than "Image" component on the button? There are some (slight) performance disadvantages, but it should be assignable directly, without the need to create an intermediate Sprite.